# Tableau server SSO credentials issues

Tags: cookies, single-sign-on, saml, tableau-api

We have a custom PHP app, and from within that there is a link that allows users to get to our tableau server. We use SSO with SAML for authentications. When a user logs into the PHP app they are authenticated with our IdP, auth0. Then when they want to go to the tableau server that sends a SAML request to auth0.

We are having 2 issues:

1) If you go directly to the tableau server (i.e. from a browser, not from the PHP app) it sends a auth request to auth0 for the Tabadmin user. If tabadmin had previously authorized with auth0 and their session has not timed out they are granted access. How can I control what username is used by tableau when none is specified?

2) When tableau gets an access request from the PHP app it checks to see if there already is a cookie and if so, logs the user in as that cookie's user (without going to auth0) even if the request is from a different user. Is there a way to fix or control that?

Comment: did u get solution for this?

Comment: No we ended up not using auth0 and doing this a different way with white listing.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit?

Comment: Sorry I did not do the white list implementation so I know nothing about it

Comment: Okay thanx for ur time :)